# Best way to store an array in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, arrays

Part of my app includes volume automation for songs.

The volume automation is described in the following format:

```
[[0,50],[20,62],[48,92]]
```

I consider each item in this array a 'data point' with the first value containing the position in the song and the second value containing the volume on a scale of 0-100.

I then take these values and perform a function client-side to interpolate this data with 'virtual' data points in order to create a bezier curve allowing smooth volume transition as an audio file is playing.

However, the need has arisen to allow a user to save this automation into the database for recall at a later date.

The datapoints can be unlimited (though in reality should never really exceed around 40-50 with most being less than 10)

Also how should I handle the data?  Should it be stored as is, in a text field?  Or should I process it in some way beforehand for optimum results?

**What data type would be best to use in MySQL to store an array?**

Comment: What is the datatype that you're working with within your app? Is it a string, an array, an object? I gather from "as is, in a text field" to mean you're representing the points as a string internally, but I might be reading that wrong.

Comment: Why not just create multiple fields with the type of INT? For example volume_min, volume_max, song_position

Comment: If you do not need to perfeorm queries searching for values in that array, you can simply use a `text` field and store a serialized version of the array (the way you posted it here is ok, `[[0,50],[20,62],[48,92]]`).

Comment: it is an array. @Lorenzo - You are correct, I have no need to perform queries on this data.  Each volume automation array will have a userid, songid and name associated with it in the table.

Comment: Are you planning to perform any computations on the data while in the db? If not, there is no harm in storing it as text (or maybe JSON, going by your format) and then reading it back into the appropriate object in memory.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured as much but wanted to check that there wasn't a preferred method conforming with best practice for this type of thing that I was missing.

Comment: How to store the matrix of the following kind in DB? int[] myIntArray = new int[1000]{1,2,3,0,1,2,1, ...} ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Definitely not a `text` field, but a `varchar` -- perhaps. I wouldn't recommend parsing the results and storing them in individual columns unless you want to take advantage of that data in database sense -- statistics etc.

If you never see yourself asking "What is the average volume that users use?" then don't bother parsing it.

To figure out how to store this data ask yourself "How will i use it later?" If you will obtain the array and need to utilize it with PHP you can use [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize) function. If you will use the values in JavaScript then JSON encoding will probably be best for you (plus many languages know how to decode it)

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect answer Mikhail thank you.  It covers all the points that were in question.

Comment: @Mikhail +1 all right, but why _Definitely not a `text` field_?

Comment: `text` is designed to store an actual text - like a story, or a poem. It's not designed to store a string. In MySQL text stores in a file rather than a "leaf of a tree." everything about it is slower, search, indexing, caching.

Comment: @Mikhail is your comment correct even when the data fits in memory?

Comment: @Kaan, I'm not aware of MySQL storing the same column in different methods depending on its contents.

Comment: @Mikhail I mean MySQL eventually persists everything to a file (save certain storage engines). But TEXT columns are only stored on a different page (based on configuration and their size) not an individual file (talking about InnoDB storage engine, but I would guess others are doing the same). Regardless, if your data fits in memory, it is going to be accessed from memory anyways. So, yes there is probably an overhead for accessing them (if they are in external pages not the row page) but I don't think that would be noticeable enough especially when data is not big as in this question

Comment: @Kaan, fair point; I shouldn't have said 'file' in my comment. Anything can be made to work, and can be optimized to where it doesn't matter. But I don't think that's what OP was wanting to know. And for someone who's learning - might as well learn the principles, and the correct way to do it.

Comment: +1 for serialize method, especially since the OP stated that client will use this data client-side and needs to store for later use. It doesn't sound like there will be a need to access individual data points by the database, hence storing the array. I use this technique frequently.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to take a look at the JSON data type. This way you can store your array in a more efficient way than text or varchar, and you can access your data directly form MySQL without having to parse the whole thing.

Take a look at this link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 4):

If speed is the most important when retrieving the rows then make a new table and make it dedicated to holding the indices of your array.  Use the data type of integer and have each row represent an index of the array.  You'll have to create another numeric column which binds these together so you can re-assemble the array with an SQL query.

This way you help MySQL help you speed up access.  If you only want certain parts of the array, you just change the range in the SQL query and you can reassemble the array however you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store array is JSON data type -

```
    CREATE TABLE example (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `docs` JSON,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


    INSERT INTO example (docs)
  VALUES ('["hot", "cold"]');
```

Read more - [https://sebhastian.com/mysql-array/#:~:text=Although%20an%20array%20is%20one,use%20the%20JSON%20data%20type](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-array/#:%7E:text=Although%20an%20array%20is%20one,use%20the%20JSON%20data%20type).