# Storing array type data in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

To try and simplify, let me see if this makes it any easier. I've created 3 fictitious JSON representation of states I want to store in MySQL. I'm looking for some suggestions as to the best way to store them. In particular the "state" data is the part that I'm not too sure how to approach.

If it helps, I'm find for creating a specific DB table per round.

User State for Round 1

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "round": 0,
    "move": 0,
    "points": 10,
    "state": [
        100, 200, 300, 10, 50
    ]
}
```

User state for Round 2

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "round": 1,
    "move": 3,
    "points": 150,
    "state": [
        10, 50, 800
    ]
}
```

User state for Round 3

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "round": 2,
    "move": 7,
    "points": 1175,
    "state": [
        [ 100, 200, 300 ],
        [ 40, 10, 20 ],
        [ 800, 1000, 50, 90, 20 ]
    ]
}
```

**Original post below**

I'm currently working on a game that utilizes MySQL. The game works on rounds, where a round represents a set of moves. Possible moves can either be represented by a one dimensional array or multi-dimensional array. For example:

```
[ 100, 200, 300, 50, 10 ]
```

or

```
[
    [ 100, 200, 300, 50, 10 ],
    [ 20, 500, 10, 5, 800 ],
    [ 5, 1, 4 ]
]
```

The values will always be integers. And as one can see, in the multi-dimensional case, each row may not be the same length. In the one-dimensional case, length can be arbitrary. However, for a given round, the array lengths are fixed. The variance of length as well as whether is is one or multi dimensional is defined per round.

One can think of the multi-dimensional case of a round that is comprised of sub-rounds. Once a sub-round is passed, it goes onto the next sub-round until all sub-rounds are completed.

A player playing a round can exit, but the state will be saved. Hence it is possible for a player to have multiple "saved" rounds.

As the player can play on different devices, I don't want to store the round state on the device. Rather I want to serve the state on demand. Currently the client submits a move to the server and the server will respond back with an updated state. But right now, there is no persistence so if the server goes down, then the state is lost (still in dev, so not an issue right now)

I'm looking for approaches towards saving this state with MySQL.

One approach I thought of was having a DB table per round, but this doesn't quite solve how the one-dimensional or multi-dimensional array would be stored. Here I'd imagine the user_id would be the primary key.

The other would be a DB table which can handle storing arbitrary data. Here I'd imagine the primary key would be a composite of user_id and round_id.

Of course there is some additional state the table would need to store like the number of moves, the points earned in the round, etc.

To represent "array data" would JSON Data Type or encoding the data in a string or binary blob be best? I would prefer something that won't consume a ton of extra time in decoding (for example, some JSON encode/decoders are not that speedy). Trying to determine some good options to try.

The server code is C++.

Comment: I have not read the question. Too long. Can you reduce that to the very core of your problem?

Comment: I've updated the question ... hopefully for the better?

Comment: And I have looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299658/best-way-to-store-an-array-in-mysql-database it is a bit old, so seeing if there is any other approaches